# Saving file contents to variables through >> operator

Tags: c++, string, file-io, operators

I am trying to read a file and then put the contents (seperator by a space) into variables.
The file's contents are always similar per line. It looks like this:

```
(50,60) CIRCLE yellow 10
(100,160) CIRCLE red 20
```

These values are position, name, colour and diameter.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Practicum week 3");
    std::ifstream input("input.txt");
    std::string name;
    std::string line;
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Color colour;

    while (std::getline(input, line))
    {
        input >> position >> name;
    }

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event Event;
        while (window.pollEvent(Event)) {
            if (Event.type == sf::Event::Closed) { window.close(); }
        }

        // Start frame
        window.clear();

        // End frame & display contents
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem here is that at the `input >> position >> name;` it gives me an error:

> "Error: no operator '>>' matches these operands"
>   operand types are: std::ifstream >> sf::vector2f

I've seen a lot of solutions to this problem being #include  missing but as you can see I've already got that covered.

Am I missing something?

Comment: What is `sf::Vector2f`? Is an `operator >>` defined for it?

Comment: @Angew sf::Vector2f is an (x,y) vector from SFML, which is basically the position of the object that I want to draw (but that's later). I haven't overloaded the >> operator, since I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: `Vector2f` has no overloaded `operator >>`, so you can't use it this way.

Comment: Well, if you haven't coded `operator >>` for it, and SFML doesn't provide one either, why do you expect using `>>` to work?

Comment: @Angew Well I didn't know SFML would have to provide one. I thought I could pass (10,20) to the Vector2f. Should I send it to a string instead and then change it into a vector2f instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The following examples will show you how to take advantage of extraction operator overloading, so that your objects can read values directly from a stream.

You need to overload the `operator >>` for your object `Vector2f`. This should look something like this:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Vector2f& v2f)
{ 
    is >> v2f.data_member >> v2f.another_data_member;
    return is;
}
```

For example, to read this format: `(50,60) CIRCLE yellow 10`, your overloaded operator should look like: <sup>*slightly in pseudo-code</sup>

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, const Any_Object& any_obj_instantiation)
{ 
    // input variables
    int first_num, second_num;
    char open_par, close_par, comma;
    Circle circle;
    Color color;
    int last_num;
    // extract ; it skips whitespaces 
    is >> open_par >> first_num >> comma >> second_num >> cirlce >> color >> last_num;
    // failed input
    if(!is) return is;
    // wrong input format
    if(open_par != '(' || close_par != ')' || comma != ','){
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        return is;
    }
    // pass the input values to the object 
    any_obj_instantiation(Vector2f(first_num, second_num), cirlce, color, last_num);

    return is;
}
```

The above code snippet could be used as a benchmark and adapted to the objects you want to populate directly with the input stream operator.

Comment: I get an error saying that istream and Object are unidentified. I tried checking if I wasn't missing an include but couldn't find anything on google for these 2 errors.

Comment: @Aydin Biber the above code is meant to be taken as a benchmark. (that's why I put that clarification: **slightly in pseudo-code** ). You just have to put any object you want in the place of `Object` and adapt the body with its members.

Comment: @simplicis_veritatis I'm not sure I understand why I need to pass anything to an object. I want to read the file and save the different values in it to variables. Do I need to make the objects that I want to draw there already? I was hoping I'd be able to do that later on in the code.

Comment: @Aydin Biber I'm adding a clarification to the answer, however, as we don't know the specificities of your objects, e.g. `Vector2f` 
`colour', we can't write the exact code.

Comment: @Aydin Biber You could **pass by reference the objects that you want to initialize** from the file and populate them with the respective values and then save them in a container of the same type, instead of saving all the values from the file in different variables, etc.

Comment: @Aydin Biber you could do it anyway you want, the above answer is just making an example of how to take advantage of extraction operator overloading, so that your objects can read values directly from a stream.

Answer (score 0):

How about stringstream?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

struct vec{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    //string s;
    //vec v;
    //stringstream ss;

    //ss << "20 10 test";
    //ss >> v.x >> v.y >> s;
    //cout << v.x << " " << v.y << " " << s.c_str(); // 20 10 test

    //@EDIT - simple parsing
    vec v;
    string s = "(2034,10)";
    size_t comaPos = s.find_first_of(',');
    string x = s.substr(1, comaPos-1);
    string y = s.substr(comaPos+1, s.find_first_of(')')-comaPos-1);

    v.x = stoi(x);
    v.y = stoi(y);

    cout << v.x << " " << v.y;

    return 0;
}
```

Note: you can't stream "(20,10)" directly to sf::Vector2f, but you can stream just the coords, as I did above.

Comment: Sadly it must be in the form of "(10,20)". I cannot add a space or seperate the characters in any other way.